# Inserting commas into values

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a field, let's call it `total_sales` where the value it returns is `3621731641`

I would like to convert that so it has a thousand separator commas inserted into it. So it would ultimately return as `3,621,731,641`

I've looked through the Redshift documentation and have not been able to find anything.

Comment: I'm not 100% if it's supported on redshift, but `TO_CHAR(<field>, '999G999G999G999')` may work.

Comment: ^ `'FM999G999G999G999'` to drop padding spaces.

Comment: @JNevill @eurotrash

Oh hell yeah! It worked. One more question. What if I wanted to both do that and convert it into money. For some reason it will return `SELECT
CAST('21398834947' AS money)` as `$9,897,812.92` which doesn't make sense

Comment: From https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=844220, "The type money is not a supported type at this point."

Comment: `select to_char(<field>, 'FM999,999,999,999') from <table>` - _it seems like i spend too much time on this page trying to piece it together.  so this one is for me_. :p

Answer (score 5):

Similar to following query should work for you.

```
select to_char(<columnname>,'999,999,999,999') from table1;
```

Make sure to put Maximum size in while specifying pattern into second parameter.
It should not give you $ if don't specify 'l' in second parameter like below.

```
select to_char(<columnname>,'l999,999,999,999') from table1;
```

Comment: the comment about using `l` to get `$` makes this answer more confusing than it needs to be.  imho.

Answer (score 0):

Money format: `select '$'||trim(to_char(1000000000.555,'999G999G999G999.99'))`

Comment: @404 has a comment that indicates using `FM999G999...` trims the padding.  seems more elegant since you're already specifying a format for `to_char` anyway...and like @red-boy points out...`l` will format it with a dollar sign.  fun concatenation of stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

`select to_char(<columnname>,'999,999,999,999') from table1;`
or
`select to_char(<columnname>,'999G999G999G999') from table1;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.